# compiler Error : Invalid type: Cache.OrgPartition

Tags: apex, compile-error, platform-cache

I am trying to use Platform cache via Apex Code.
1. Created a new platform cache partition in my org - 10MB assigned to Org Cache.
[image]

Then created a simple apex class via dev console to access the partition, but just the declaration of the variable gives me a compiler error : Invalid type: Cache.OrgPartition

```
public class testpartition { 
    private Cache.OrgPartition part; 
}
```

Has anyone encountered this before? Any advice as to where am i going wrong?

Comment: Did someone define a custom `Cache` class in your org?

Comment: spot on ! thanks Adrian ! yes there is a custom Cache class.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this sort of error crops up when someone introduces a naming collision (i.e. a custom `Cache` class). You can remove vulnerability to this sort of naming collision by referencing `System.Cache.OrgPartition` instead:

```
private System.Cache.OrgPartition part;
```

Comment: hello Adrian, I tried your suggested option of using System.Cache but still the get the same error at the declaration. screenshot attached.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your suggested option of using System.Cache but still the get the same error at the declaration. screenshot attached.[image]